# Como utilizar o gulp para auto copiar os arquivos de fonte ao compilar scss?

Tags: gulp, laravel

Estou utilizando o gulp com gulp-sass para gerar o build dos meus arquivos css. Gostaria de ao fazer o build do SCSS, os arquivos de fonte referenciados por **@font-face** dentro do estilo fossem automaticamente copiado para **assets/fonts**, enquanto que o css seria gerado em **assets/css**. Atualmente efetuo o build do scss com a task abaixo:

```
gulp.task('scss', function () {
    return gulp.src('scss/estilo.scss')
            .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'expanded'}).on('error', sass.logError))
            .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'));
});
```

Já o arquivo **scss/estilo.scss** contem o conteúdo:

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

Seria uma ideia parecida com a do Laravel-mix, o qual lê o arquivo scss ou sass e copia os arquivos referenciados por url()

Utilizo o gulp versão:

- CLI version 1.4.0
- Local version 3.9.1